# Creating a graphical representation of connections in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, relationship, erd

I have another Microsoft Access question:

I am building a contact database, and some of these contacts have relationships with each other. For example, two contacts in the database might be brother and sister, and I will have marked their relationship within the database accordingly. I can generate a report with SQL that will give me the information that I want (i.e. who is related to what person). However, the problem is not the information itself, but how I would like to display said information.

Instead of a list format detailing every contact somehow related to the person in question. I would like to graphically represent a web of people. So if John Doe is the brother of Scott Doe and a sister of Jane Doe, then the Access report would have John Doe's name in the middle and then two lines coming out of the name pointing to Scott Doe and Jane Doe.

I am not even sure if this graphical representation is possible in Access, which is why I'm curious to know if anyone has ever attempted this before or if it is even possible. And then, how would one go about setting that up programmatically?

I realize that this is a fairly open-ended question, but any help would be much appreciated. For the record, I am proficient in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider introducing a treeview control.  And since you don't know how many levels, then in our industry, we typically use what is called recursion.

There is an example here of code to fill the treeview:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209891